# which usage is better: upon or with?

Tags: phrase-usage

"peace be upon you/him/her" or "peace be with you/him/her"

"May God's mercy be upon you/him/her" or "May God's mercy be with you/him/her"

Answer (score 1):

In Galatians 6:16, Paul the apostle says [KJV translation] :

> And as many as walk by this rule, peace be upon them and upon the Israel of God.

In John 20:21, Jesus says to the disciples :

> Peace to you.

In I Peter 5:14, Peter the apostle says :

> Peace be with you all

So it would seem, from three different individuals recorded in the bible, that there is a variety of ways of pronouncing peace.

[These are all accurate translations from the original Greek.]